# How to draw a curve on 2 points (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android

I have a two points, but I don't know start and end angles, and I need draw a curve on this points. Help me please. Thank you for helping, anyway.

Comment: you cannot define a unique curve by two points only a unique line segment. you need more information than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a infinite number of curves with two points.  You need a radius point to draw a circle arc.